# Copy specific text from notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have some text in notepad++ like this. I would like to get copy the text in quotes in the line, whose next line have text as "No links found"

```
links in 'abc' as of time-spec 'now':
 No links found.

links in 'def' as of time-spec 'now':
 No links found.

links in 'xsdsw' as of time-spec 'now':
 dferg,regerg,grgerg
 No of links found: 3
```

Desired Output (Intermediate):

```
links in 'abc' as of time-spec 'now':
 No xlinks found.

links in 'def' as of time-spec 'now':
 No xlinks found.
```

Desired Output (final) :

```
abc
def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a perfect solution, but could help if you have no other way.

With your file open, do a Find operation using the **regular expression** search mode. Use the following for your find criteria (adjust as needed):

```
links in '(.*)' as of time-spec 'now':\r\n No links found.
```

[image: "Find" dialog]

Click **"Find All in Current Document"** and you will get results that look similar to the following:

[image: Results pane]

In the results pane you should be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click and highlight the text within the single-quotes. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the values and then you can paste them into a new document or wherever you want them. *Note: if the text within quotes is of varying length, you'll have to select more than you need in order to highlight each line as well as manually modify the pasted text to have a clean result.*

[image: Results pane with highlighted characters]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use Replace with two sequential regular expressions. With your document open, press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to get the Replace dialog.

First, for "**Find what**" use:

```
links in '(.*)' as of time-spec 'now':\r\n.*\r\n No of links found: \d*\r\n
```

Leave "**Replace with**" as an empty text box. Click "Replace All" and this should effectively delete the lines you don't care to see.

Second, leave the Replace dialog open and now enter the following expression for "**Find what**"

```
links in '(.*)' as of time-spec 'now':\r\n No links found.\r\n
```

For "**Replace with**", put the following: `\1`

Click "Replace All" again and it should leave you with just the values you were looking to keep.

[image: Animation of above steps]